# Json post int type is always 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
[HttpPost("method")]
public string Method(int number)
{
    return number.ToString();
}
```

Why number is always 0?

Its possible to use json post with primitive types like this?

My post: { "number" : 3 }

Comment: You should add a decorator to specify where to find the information, e.g. `public string Post([FromQuery] int number)` to get it from the Uri or [FromBody] to get it from the Post Body. But in my experience it is much easier to use explicit types instead of primitive types if you want to get it from the message body.

Comment: Did not succeed with [FromQuery]. If i try with string or using two int parameters, i dont have problem. =/

Comment: If you use FromQuery you need to call your method like this: http://localhost/method?number=3 - if you want to call it like you initially did you need to use FromBody.

Comment: Apparently, FromBody doesn't work with just one int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you post data like `{ "number" : 3 }`, your action method should be

```
public class Data
{
   public int Number {get; set;}
}

[HttpPost("method")]
public string Method([FromBody] Data data)
{
    return data.Number.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NumberModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("method")]
public IActionResult Method([FromBody] NumberModel model)
{
    return Ok(model.Number);
}
```

Will auto format it as Json. As Number is an integer, it will return as the string representation of the number. If you just return `Ok(model)` it will return an json object like `{ 'Number' : 3 }`